# Django multiple Foreign Key - Display related field in details admin page for add/edit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a polling app with one of the models "Choice" consisting of 2 Foreign key fields linked to the "Person" model.

I wanted to automatically populate related "photo_other" field (with the image link) once I have selected the "name" of the person. "name" is also a Foreign Key Field linked with Choice model.

**models.py**

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    photo_other = models.ForeignKey(Person) 
    rating = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
  return smart_unicode(self.name)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
  return smart_unicode(self.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to store the same value in two different tables when they are connected through a `foreign key`? It just doesn't make sense.

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    rating = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def photo_other(self):
        return self.name.photo

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

---

In order to make `photo_other` visible under the admin page of `Choice` model, you can do the following;

```
class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'rating', 'get_photo']

    def get_photo(self, obj):
        return obj.photo_other
    get_photo.short_description = 'Photo'
```

Comment: thanks. This is not working though. I do not see the related fields in the admin

Comment: I added the property in my models as mentioned above and it did not show the photo field on admin details page.

Comment: thanks, it works partly as it only shows this section in the list display and not in the details page. any suggestions for that?